# How to gain access to various TFS build definition parameters

Tags: tfs

I am creating custom TFS activities.  It seems the default pattern everyone uses is to create a variable in the XAML, set it using some TFS activity, and then pass that into your custom TFS activity.  This seems very primitive and in practice it's very troublesome.  If the interface to your TFS activity changes, the XAML just blows up losing all the settings you had for the activity to begin with.

My belief is that the CodeActivityContext object that is passed to the custom activity has everything I need, but I am missing how to gain access to certain properties.

So for example, I have a base TFS Activity class that currently does the following...

```
public abstract class ActivityBase : CodeActivity
{
    protected CodeActivityContext _context;
    protected IBuildAgent _buildAgent;
    protected IBuildDetail _buildDetail;
    protected IBuildDefinition _buildDefinition;
    protected string _buildDirectory;

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        _buildAgent = context.GetExtension<IBuildAgent>();
        _buildDetail = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
        _buildDefinition = _buildDetail.BuildDefinition;
        _buildDirectory = _buildAgent.GetExpandedBuildDirectory(_buildDefinition);

        Execute();
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();
}
```

Notice I can get access to the BuildDefinition, and I am certain that is a gateway to my custom XAML properties that are set by the user.  However, I don't see how to gain access to them?

Also, I would like to gain access to the ProjectsToBuild setting (which is an Argument in the default XAML).

There are other things I need as well, but if I can get a handle on these first things, I should be able to figure out the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to access "ProjectsToBuild"

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    var props = context.DataContext.GetProperties();
    var bsProp = props["BuildSettings"];
    var buildSettings = (BuildSettings) bsProp.GetValue(context.DataContext);

    if (buildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild)
    {
        context.TrackBuildMessage("Projects to build:", BuildMessageImportance.High);
        foreach (var project in buildSettings.ProjectsToBuild)
        {
            context.TrackBuildMessage(project, BuildMessageImportance.High);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.TrackBuildMessage("No 'Projects to build' in build definition", BuildMessageImportance.High);
    }
}
```

That way you can access (read-only) everything listed in Arguments tab of XAML editor of build template.

```
var props = context.DataContext.GetProperties();
foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
{
    context.TrackBuildMessage(string.Format("{0}: {1}", prop.Name,  prop.GetValue(context.DataContext)), BuildMessageImportance.High);    
}
```

Accessing "ProjectsToBuild" from IBuildDefinition is also possible (which you tried to do), but is useful from other places than build extensions:

```
new List<string>() projectsToBuild = new List<string>();

IDictionary<string, object> deserializedProcessParameters = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters);

if (deserializedProcessParameters.ContainsKey("BuildSettings"))
{
    BuildSettings buildSettings = (BuildSettings)deserializedProcessParameters["BuildSettings"];

    if (null != buildSettings) 
        projectsToBuild = buildSettings.ProjectsToBuild;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way to access your custom, or any, build workflow properties is to pass them in. They are not acessable in any other way from within a CodeActivity. This is a feature, or not, of Windows Workflow.